# Upload files to wp-content/uploads - What to add in DB?

Tags: uploads

Given that I upload a file to `wp-content/uploads` via FTP, what are the records that I should create in the DB in order for the MediaManager to recognize those new uploads?

Comment: May I ask for the reason you want to bypass WordPress?

Comment: I want to avoid having write permissions in that folder for now.

Comment: do it locally on your own machine then copy the results up, or put in write permissions temporarily

Answer (score 2):

There is [`media_handle_sideload()`](http://queryposts.com/function/media_handle_sideload/) function in core meant for processing files not uploaded through media interface.

It's not exactly what you need since it assumes file is *outside* of uploads and needs to be moved there as part of process, but it should give you and idea on generating and inserting it as valid attachment.

Answer (score 1):

> ... what are the records that I should create in the DB in order for
>   the MediaManager to recognize those new uploads?

Honestly, I don't know what the *minimum* required data is but...

1. WordPress stored the primary data in the `$wpdb->posts` table as an
   `attachment` post type.
2. And significant meta data is stored in the `$wpdb->postmeta` table
   under at least two keys (that I can spot at a glance)--
   `_wp_attached_file` and `_wp_attachment_metadata`.

I am sure you will have to populate at least the `$wpdb->post` table. You may be able to neglect some of the post meta, but I don't know for sure.

At any rate, don't try to construct the data yourself. Crawl the directory and use Core functions to do the work for your, or use a plugin that does it for you, [such as this one](http://wordpress.org/plugins/media-from-ftp/).  I can't vouch for it but it seems to be close to what you need.